# GNU/Guix USB .iso boot failure

Tags: linux, boot, usb, partitioning, grub

I created a - what I believed to be - bootable GNU-Guix USB.
Selected USB as priority startup device.
I get a Grub Rescue screen.
On that screen I can ls two partitions - hd0, and hd1. I'm certain the hd0 is the USB.
The hd0 has a filesystem under it named something like ISO9966. I can enter that filesystem, and see various files, such as 'boot', GNU, etc.

I wish to install Guix alongside Windows 11, in - of course separate - partitions.

I formatted the hard drive in Windows 11, creating an exFAT.

Subsequently -

I repeated the entire process using Rufus from within Windows 11. I used the DD option. I booted with the USB. The boot process completed and the Guix installation process began. I got to a screen/input frame, it says something along the lines of 'no ethernet service available', and a 'try again' button.

It may be that my wireless adapter, which is a - Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-ac 8260 - isn't supported by Linux-Libre. I'll next research whether it is. I'll either find the correct driver, or I'll attempt to write it myself.

Comment: Did you backup your existing Windows installation and did you check that your backup is intact?

Comment: I didn't. I'm not overly concerned about that as there is nothing on it. It simply was pre-installed with the laptop I recently bought. I'm doing to try over again from withing Windows11 using Rufus. And yes, the Windows11 OS is intact and working, I'm using it right now.

Comment: Rufus writes the images bit-by-bit. This is not going to work with windows ISOs. Use the microsoft media creation tool or WoeUSB instead.